# Duplicate Topic Title search from 1 poster

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a old forum. In this forum are many double Topics (same title). I found all double topic titles with this selection:

```
SELECT topic_title, topic_time, forum_id, topic_first_post_id, topic_first_poster_name, topic_id, topic_poster, COUNT( * ) TotalCount
FROM phpbb3_topics
GROUP BY topic_title
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
```

Now I want all double topic titles from the same person `topic_poster`

Would you please show me a solution? Please edit my existend selection in the way to show all double topic titles with the same `topic_poster ID` (topic_poster is a ID field)

Thank you very much

Comment: Er, GROUP BY person, topic_title... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT topic_poster_id, topic_title, topic_time, forum_id, topic_first_post_id, topic_first_poster_name, topic_id, topic_poster, COUNT( * ) TotalCount
FROM phpbb3_topics
GROUP BY topic_poster_id, topic_title
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add the `topic_poster` to your group by:

```
SELECT topic_title, topic_time, forum_id, topic_first_post_id, topic_first_poster_name, topic_id, topic_poster, COUNT( * ) TotalCount 
FROM phpbb3_topics
GROUP BY topic_title, topic_poster
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
```

Comment: yes, done! very easy / what a shame :) topic closed! thank you so much